# Is it possible to detect and filter noise on an earth?

Tags: earth

I ask because I have a solar array on my house with micro inverters. The monitor (an Enphase Envoy) no longer detects the the inverters. Troubleshooting suggests noise on the earth, perhaps caused by transformers and motors. A suggested remedy is to plug it into a circuit that is not protected i.e. no safety switch - my shed is not protected and the Envoy detects all 16 panels while plugged in there.

Using the Envoy in the shed is not ideal because I can't see it daily and it's too far from my WiFi which it needs so my question is this:

Is there a method to detect noise on my earth and/or is there a device that I can use to filter it i.e. can I plug my Envoy into filter then into the wall?

Comment: Presuming the system used to be monitorable, what changed?

Comment: My guess is an ageing fridge and any number of kids appliances that have ac/dc transformers.

Comment: Perhaps your microinverters are not happy with the reactive loads offered. Turn on many incandescent bulbs (resistors) and see if anything changes.